# SSH - Getting 'Broken pipe' error when trying to configure multi-hop connection

Tags: linux, ssh, mac-osx

I have two SSH servers: ServerA that supports key-based authentication, and is accessible from my workstation, and ServerB that only supports password-based auth, and can only be accessed from ServerA. My goal is to SSH into ServerB from my workstation, but I'm getting a very useless error. Here's my `~/.ssh/config` file:

```
Host ServerA
    HostName 10.8.0.1
    User ubuntu
    Port 22
    IdentityFile ~\.ssh\id_server_a.pem

Host ServerB
    ServerAliveInterval 120
    HostName 12.34.56.78
    User myuser
    Port 12221
    ProxyCommand ssh -W %h:%p ServerA
```

This should work, but when I type in the command `ssh ServerB`, I get the following error:

```
/bin/sh: No such file or directory
banner exchange: Connection to UNKNOWN port 65535: Broken pipe
```

I have tested both SSH connections, as in I'm able to explicitly connect to ServerA with the key, and from ServerA's shell I'm able to connect to ServerB with the port, username and password.

Where does this error originate from (Workstation, ServerA or ServerB) and is there anything I can do to fix it?

Comment: (1) Check that /bin/sh Exists on all 3 machines. (2) Execute `ssh -vvvv ....` to get more Detail on what is going on. (3) Why you are giving %h:%p in ProxyCommand ? (4) Check with `ProxyCommand ssh -vvvv ServerA` to connect to Port 22. (5) Check `ProxyCommand ssh -vvvv ubuntu@10.8.0.1` , to get Debug Data.

Comment: This is tagged `linux` but what is your Workstation?  Specifically, both OS type and OS version.

Answer (score 2):

###### If the client system is a Mac - a Ventura upgrade is likely the cause.

Based on the timing of the OP's question, that seems quite plausible.
Upgrading my Mac to Ventura (MacOS 13.4) broke ssh for me, giving me a very similar error:

```
Infinite reexec detected; aborting
banner exchange: Connection to UNKNOWN port 65535: Broken pipe
```

#### One significant caveat - I'm using a PIV (smartcard) to authenticate

After troubleshooting with IT support the solution turned out to be:

1. Remove / comment out the `PKCS11Provider` line in your `~/.ssh/config`
2. Run the following commands:

   ```
   ssh-add -e /usr/lib/ssh-keychain.dylib
     #Note - above command may produce the error:  
     #   'Could not remove card "/usr/lib/ssh-keychain.dylib": agent refused operation'
     #This can be ignored; the file simply has no items to remove
   ssh-add -D
   killall -9 ssh-agent
   ssh-add -s /usr/lib/ssh-keychain.dylib
   ```
3. You should now be able to ssh

<sub>*Note*: *If ssh still fails* - The `killall` should have cleared all cached ssh process/keys/etc.  A reboot will definitely clear any cached data that may be interfering.</sub>

Comment: Does this mean we can't use PKCS11Provider anymore?  I also had this problem on Ventura using ssh keys.

Comment: @Angelo - Not exactly.  I just needed to comment out my `PKCS11Provider /usr/lib/ssh-keychain.dylib` line in the .ssh/config.  But the library `/usr/lib/ssh-keychain.dylib` is still being used, just that it's now being loaded via `ssh-add`.  If you had some other lib for the PKCS11Provider, I expect it should still also work using the ssh-add.

Comment: ssh-add means you're adding your PIV to your agent, and not using the PKCS11Provider directive.  I have commented out PKCS11Provider and this does prevent the problem for me, even though I've been using an ssh key.